# Firebase firestore async/await not writing in sequence

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase and have created a cloud function for doing some firestore write tasks however I am unable to get them to write in sequence as my logs come back typically in this type of random order:

```
markets_page_4 successfully updated
markets_page_1 successfully updated
markets_page_5 successfully updated
markets_page_2 successfully updated
markets_page_3 successfully updated
```

I need them to write in sequence from 1 - 5 to continue onto my next phase of logic, I have attempted to implement async/await but it seems like I am missing a key component, I will post my code below:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions
.pubsub.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {

    updateMarketsData(1);
    updateMarketsData(2);
    updateMarketsData(3);
    updateMarketsData(4);
    updateMarketsData(5);

    return null;
});    

/**
 *
 * @param {number} page
 */
async function updateMarketsData(page) {

    await firestore.collection(collectionId)
    .doc(docId).update({
      markets_array: homeTimelineRequestText,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("markets_page_" + page + " successfully updated");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error writing document " + page, error);
    });

}
```

Comment: What are `collectionId`, `docId` and `homeTimelineRequestText`, where do they come from (and what do they have to do with the `page` parameter)? Why is the order so important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `await` inside your `updateMarketsData`, that function itself also executes asynchronously. Using `await` doesn't get rid of the asynchronous behavior. That's also why you had to mark your `updateMarketsData` function as `async` itself too.

---

So when you call `updateMarketsData`, you have to use `await` there too:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions
.pubsub.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun(async (context) => {

    await updateMarketsData(1);
    await updateMarketsData(2);
    await updateMarketsData(3);
    await updateMarketsData(4);
    await updateMarketsData(5);

    return null;
});
```

You'll note that the anonymous callback function we pass to `onRun` is now marked as `async` too, for the same reason as above.

---

If you don't care about the exact order in which the updates execute, but just that they all completely before the `onRun` callback completes, you can also use `Promise.all` instead:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions
.pubsub.schedule("every 2 minutes").onRun((context) => {

  return Promise.all([
    updateMarketsData(1);
    updateMarketsData(2);
    updateMarketsData(3);
    updateMarketsData(4);
    updateMarketsData(5);
  ]);

});
```

Now you no longer have to mark the `onRun` callback as `async`, since we no longer use `await` in this function body.

An advantage of this approach is that the updates now all start (and likely execute) in parallel, so they may complete faster (and definitely not slower) than the earlier solution where we only start each subsequent update after the previous one is done.

Comment: The order is really important so I attempted to add await to my updateMarketData() function but because it's being called within a firebase exports function I get this error:      'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: I missed a key addition to the code where you added "async" to the inner function, after doin that they seem to be executing in order